# Using stat_ecdf in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce a similar figure

[ggplot2_ecdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYjgT.png)

My Data looks like this

```
  Category Value
  A          2
  A          3
  A          4
  A          2
  A          4
  B          2
  B          1
  B          6
  C          1
  C          2
  C          3
  C          3
```

I would like to plot the distribution with the category as X-axes and the values in y-axes. Since some of them have similar values, using the stat_ecdf () would be great to visualize the distribution with curves for the categories to horizontally displace similar points (similar to the figure in the link).

I used the beeswarm plot in ggplot but would like to use stat_ecdf to get a displaced distribution (showing each entry as dots per category). And also add a median line in red.

What I tried

```
a <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=value)) +
stat_ecdf()+
scale_y_continuous() +
theme_light() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
xlab('category') +
ylab('values')
a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am a bit limited on time today, but maybe this can point you in the right direction.

```
a <- ggplot(data = df,
            aes(x = value)) +
       stat_ecdf(geom = "point",
                 size = 1,
                 pad = FALSE) +
       xlab("category") +
       ylab("values") +
       facet_wrap(~ Category,
                  scales = "free_x",
                  strip.position = "bottom") +
       coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
       theme_minimal() +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank())

a
```

Update:
I played around a bit more. Hopefully this looks a bit better.

Comment: Thanks Rico does not work. The axes do not look right also. I will look into the strips theme.

Comment: I played around a bit more. Hopefully this looks a bit better. I think the y-axis is still not correct, and the text/axis on the top of the graph is not there yet. Can you somehow create how the plot should look like based on your example data?

Comment: Thanks looks great. I am trying not to have facets, and jus make each category distribution as one vertical line in the same plot

Comment: I doubt if it is possible without using facets. If you got, please let me know. I'am very curious.

Comment: I tried but could not, came across this function called tcgaCompare from maftools that does this but only for a specific data. Trying to tweak it now.